# ROS launchfile to set variable value

Tags: c++, parameters, launch, ros

I have two different but related questions

1st: Is it possible to set the value of a variable using the launch file?
I read about it online but I couldn't understand how to use it.

2nd: I couldn't find anything on how to use the launch file to set the value of a variable in a message. for instance if I have:

**mymessagevector.msg:**

```
mymessage myvector[2]
```

**mymessage.msg:**

```
int32 value
string ID
```

Is there a way to set the myvector[0].ID="ID1" and myvector[1].ID="ID2" and always publish that without having to define it everytime I sent the message to a topic?

Answer (score 1):

The first answer could be easily found in the [roslaunch documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) (and relative subsections).

A simple example is the following:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="pkg_name" type="node_type" name="node_name">
    <param name="var_name" type="var_type" value="var_value" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

You could find the meanings of all these parameters in the following links: [param](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param) and [node](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node).

I am sorry, but I don't know how could be initialized a "first message" using roslaunch (if it is possible...). You could use a variable instead.

**UPDATE:**

I'll show you an example in a c++ file

```
/* Retrieves information from parameters (if there are some specified) */

/* this handle let you access all the parameters of the node (and other stuffs) */
ros::NodeHandle node_handle = new ros::NodeHandle("~");

/* for example I need to retrieve the name of the serial port which is a parameter of my node */
std::string serial_port = "";
/* this member function searches for the parameter and stores it into 'serial_port' if it exists, 
 * otherwise it uses the third parameter of the function (a default value) */
node_handle->param("<name_of_param_in_roslaunch>", serial_port, std::string(DEFAULT_VALUE));
```

You can find the `ros::NodeHandle` documentation [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html).

Comment: What I don't understand is how to use it afterwards. I'm defining a variable there, but I need to declare that variable in my cpp and it should automatically get that value, right? I thought it was like this but I am no able to do it.

Comment: I've added a c++ example in the answer. Hope it helps.